# Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, truffle

I am trying to run some tests on a smart contract I created and keep receiving the message

> Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider

Essentially my smart contract is for a supply chain and it emits events whenever a certain step of the supply chain is crossed. In my test I am trying to listen for those events and assert that the event took place.

I have used ChatGPT to try and debug this and implemented a few of his suggestions, but the issue persists.

The test (snippet):

```
// 1st Test
  it("Testing smart contract function harvestItem() that allows a farmer to harvest coffee", async () => {
    const supplyChain = await SupplyChain.deployed();

    // Watch the emitted event Harvested()
    const event = supplyChain.Harvested();
    console.log("Waiting for Harvested event...");

    // Create a promise to listen for the event
    const eventEmitted = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      event
        .on("data", (res) => {
          console.log("Harvested event emitted:", res);
          resolve(true);
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          console.log("Harvested event error:", error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });

    // Wait for the event to be emitted
    const isEventEmitted = await eventEmitted;
    console.log("Harvested event received:", isEventEmitted);

    // Mark an item as Harvested by calling function harvestItem()
    await supplyChain.harvestItem(
      upc,
      originFarmerID,
      originFarmName,
      originFarmInformation,
      originFarmLatitude,
      originFarmLongitude,
      productNotes
    );

    // Retrieve the just now saved item from blockchain by calling function fetchItem()
    const resultBufferOne = await supplyChain.fetchItemBufferOne.call(upc);
    const resultBufferTwo = await supplyChain.fetchItemBufferTwo.call(upc);

    // Verify the result set
    assert.equal(isEventEmitted, true, "Invalid event emitted");
```

The relevant function in the contract:

```
// Define a function 'harvestItem' that allows a farmer to mark an item 'Harvested'
    function harvestItem(
        uint _upc,
        address _originFarmerID,
        string memory _originFarmName,
        string memory _originFarmInformation,
        string memory _originFarmLatitude,
        string memory _originFarmLongitude,
        string memory _productNotes
    ) public onlyOperational {
        // Add the new item as part of Harvest
        items[_upc] = Item({
            sku: sku,
            upc: _upc,
            ownerID: _originFarmerID,
            originFarmerID: _originFarmerID,
            originFarmName: _originFarmName,
            originFarmInformation: _originFarmInformation,
            originFarmLatitude: _originFarmLatitude,
            originFarmLongitude: _originFarmLongitude,
            productID: sku + _upc,
            productNotes: _productNotes,
            productPrice: 0, // Set initial price. Can be updated later
            itemState: defaultState,
            distributorID: address(0),
            retailerID: address(0),
            consumerID: address(0)
        });
        // Increment sku
        sku++;
        // Emit the appropriate event
        emit Harvested(_upc);
    }
```

ChatGPT suggested that I use a WebSocketProvider instead of an HttpProvider and update my truffle-config.js file as follows:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Web3WsProvider = require("web3-providers-ws");

// Initialize web3 using WebSocketProvider
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3WsProvider("ws://localhost:8545"));

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      provider: web3,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.19",
    },
  },
};
```

But the issue persists. Has anyone come across this by any chance?

Here is the full error message:

```
Contract: SupplyChain
Waiting for Harvested event...
Harvested event error: Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/.../Ethereum_Supply_Chain_Project/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/lib/subscription.js:176:1)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    1) Testing smart contract function harvestItem() that allows a farmer to harvest coffee
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (79ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: SupplyChain
       Testing smart contract function harvestItem() that allows a farmer to harvest coffee:
     Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider
      at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/.../Ethereum_Supply_Chain_Project/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/lib/subscription.js:176:1)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```